# Hibernate @SecondaryTables multiple pkJoinColumns

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I´m having an error with a @SecondaryTable when one of the Entity has an @EmbeddedId with more primary keys than the second entity´s @EmbeddedId. When I deploy in the server it says:

> SecondaryTable JoinColumn cannot reference a non primary key

I think it´s better to explain with an example:

**Database Tables**

```
create table FIRST_TABLE
(
    ID_ONE          VARCHAR2(2) not NULL,
    ID_TWO          VARCHAR2(20) not NULL,
    DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR2(50) not NULL,
    constraint VIEW_CFG_PK primary key (ID_ONE, ID_TWO)
        using index tablespace DEMO_IDX
        storage (initial 100K next 50K pctincrease 0 maxextents unlimited)
)

create table SECOND_TABLE
(
    ID_ONE          VARCHAR2(2) not NULL,
    ID_TWO          VARCHAR2(20) not NULL,
    ID_THREE        NUMBER(3) not NULL,
    ID_FOUR         NUMBER(3) not NULL,
    DESCRIPTION     VARCHAR2(50) not NULL,
    COLOR           VARCHAR2(50),
    constraint VIEW_CFG_PK primary key (ID_ONE, ID_TWO, ID_THREE, ID_FOUR)
        using index tablespace DEMO_IDX
        storage (initial 100K next 50K pctincrease 0 maxextents unlimited)
)
```

With these tables I create two @Entity in Java like these ones:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FIRST_TABLE")
@NamedQuery(name = "FirstTable.findAll", query = "SELECT ft FROM FIRST_TABLE ft")
public class FirstTable implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private FirstTablePK id;

    private String description;

    public FirstTable () {
    }
...

@Embeddable
public class FirstTablePK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ID_ONE")
    private String idOne;

    @Column(name = "ID_TWO")
    private String idTwo;

    public FirstTablePK () {
    }
...


@Entity
@Table(name = "SECOND_TABLE")
@NamedQuery(name = "SecondTable.findAll", query = "SELECT st FROM SecondTable st")
@SecondaryTable(name="FIRST_TABLE", pkJoinColumns = {
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID_ONE", referencedColumnName="ID_ONE"),
        @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID_TWO", referencedColumnName="ID_TWO")
})
public class SecondTable implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private SecondTablePK id;

    private String color;

    private String description;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", table = "FIRST_TABLE")
    private String descriptionFirst;

    public SecondTable() {
    }
...

@Embeddable
public class SecondTablePK implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ID_ONE")
    private String idOne;

    @Column(name = "ID_TWO")
    private String idTwo;

    @Column(name = "ID_THREE")
    private long idThree;

    @Column(name = "ID_FOUR")
    private long idFour;

    public SecondTablePK() {
    }
```

I´m joining tables with PrimaryKeys, but Server error still says that I can´t not join with Non Primary Keys.

I put error log:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: SecondaryTable JoinColumn cannot reference a non primary key
```

Edited:

What I want to do is that, for example, when I make a findAll request to SECOND_TABLE, get all the SecondTable entities with its own columns and its related table FIRST_TABLE´s "Description" column too.

Like this:

```
select st.ID_ONE, st.ID_TWO, ... st.DESCRIPTION, ft.DESCRIPTION as descriptionFirst 
from SECOND_TABLE st
join FIRST_TABLE ft on ft.ID_ONE = st.ID_ONE AND ft.ID_TWO = st.ID_TWO;
```

Comment: Well the error is pretty clear. Maybe it is some other type of relationship you want?

Comment: What do you mean with another type of relationship? It´s a @ManyToOne relationship, but instead of get all the model, I only need "Description" parameter for FIRST_TABLE. I´m maybe doing it wrong

Comment: Ok Alan, but do you know where is the mistake or how to solve it? Could be that both @Entity must have the same amount of Primary Keys?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem Ask a question about the problem you want to solve and not about your perceived (and completely incorrect) solution.

Comment: Sorry Alan, my mistake, I was explaining bad, I change to what I want to achieve; it was clear I´m doing something wrong. Thx for your attention.